# Basic PGP Encryption / Decryption

Tags: encryption, pgp, decryption

I am working on a project that requires the basic encryption/decryption of a message. I generated private/public keys with my email and no password. The pgp public key as well as the private key, appear to be in the following format (appears to be base64_encoded):

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0

rwd3434f...key..4d44edw4
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

This public key was then used to encrypt some message. I then received this sample non-encoded encrypted message in a (*.pgp) file that I need to decrypt using the private key generated.

```
WEÛπ*=‚d\Ì˝¯i⁄„˝∂FŒ™ç;ı\qä´©Õ·[. G»v‹4Ø˘∂0J˘ÏN8¡6ÓÿÖ÷Á{x_>À5ÉQug‘Ô}ôΩ\ò[@$¶rnò∂sƒ1E∂˛ 9M!üæd<˝GŸ^páwS”ö`Uó˙L"ª∑â˛T“û0EUΩÉ'£éZ¢Ïg∂ﬁH13èóƒíÁ⁄!∞èñ4ù(ÂC2ábñ§¥ªµìÀ(õ(Ô1'ü¥ªçh4
îD¬r?7œƒ?+†#ßGµ?±î<›+ä’ºÖ
```

My question is what is the simplest way to decrypt this encrypted message within the .pgp file?

I tried the following online tool: https://www.igolder.com/pgp/decryption/

but keep getting a `unknown object in stream 22` error

Comment: To clarify: you control the public and private key used in these examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tool requires you to use ASCII armored encrypted files.  Your example has issues as the encoding on a binary file as displayed in a text-editor is not unique (and the web application doesn't know how to interpret it properly).

The easiest way is to just use the command line with gpg ([gpg and PGP are generally compatible when they follow the OpenPGP standard](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/if-pgp-and-gpg-both-follow-the-openpgp-standard-are-they-100-compatible-in-all) except in a few rare cases).  For a complete example, you create a trusted key pair (again for this demo I chose no passphrase on the key) with:

```
$ gpg --gen-key
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20; Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA (default)
[...]
Your selection? 1
[...]
Key expires at Thu 26 Oct 2017 01:58:43 PM EDT
Is this correct? (y/N) y

[...]
You selected this USER-ID:
    "john doe (don't use) <j@j.com>"
[...]    
gpg: key DA65E019 marked as ultimately trusted
public and secret key created and signed.
```

which in my case created a new trusted keypair called DA65E019.

Then I can encrypt a file without ASCII armoring it (basically encrypting in base64 with linebreaks):

```
$ gpg --encrypt --recipient DA65E019 test.txt
```

that creates a file called `test.txt.gpg` or with ASCII armoring it:

```
$ gpg --encrypt --armor --recipient DA65E019 test.txt
```

which creates an ASCII armored file called `test.txt.asc`.

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

hIwDLaGCjcd4AvcBA/wLm/sLb5yha7dPIz4288dtgR0a4zdynB+MZ1ikH8aVWi8x
w6aR3DoA5IyOQkg7whC2vWlWHaJLkrSOWYwnvHVSNm/bXVtXkLq9ZLWnvLVjux+E
+GVQDr8nCSdGR04ZfQ741LjDWubUzlZFacIlMuSmvMrfepIcl5i1ydr4UNA9OtJR
Ac0pgzY3odsl8nmcO+v9XmRpekDm8O3TTHAHN5ci1+iqxI6W/VOEHeuan8HW00Hh
E10+X0Sb5cNCNJBtrIE4G06F2JMKt53o4kTULiSPjT8A
=WEJE
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

I can use your tool to decrypt this message with your online tool, by exporting my secret key:

```
$ gpg --armor --export-secret-key DA65E019
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=yKJT
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

or directly decrypt the binary file `test.txt.gpg` with gpg in the commandline:

```
$ gpg --decrypt test.txt.gpg
gpg: encrypted with 1024-bit RSA key, ID C77802F7, created 2017-10-25
      "john doe (don't use) <j@j.com>"
this is a file
```

In your example, you'll have to import the private key:

```
$ gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import secret_key.gpg.asc
```

and then should be have the private key and can use it for decryption.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there a way to use an existing public / private key with gpg cli?

Comment: Followed the examples you mentioned, with creating a new key and getting the following error when trying to decrypt: `unknown object in stream SecretSubkey`

Comment: Note, `Version: GnuPG v1` isn't included in my encrypted message.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in this line:

```
 Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0
```

A quick search online says it was encrypted using the Bouncy Castle PGP library, so that's probably the best library to use to decrypt it.  This link http://rafayal.blogspot.com/2009/06/pgp-decryption-with-c.html includes an example C# program using Bouncy Castle to decrypt a PGP encrypted message.